# Circe decode case class

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have a *case class* as following:

```
case class Road(id: String, light: TrafficLight, cars: Map[String, String])
```

Simply, I'm trying to **decode** Json to **List[Road]**.
The Json I'm trying to decode is:

```
[   
   {
        "id" = "A",
        "light" = "green",
        "cars": [
          {
            "Nissan" : "100"
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `TrafficLight` is basic enum:

```
object TrafficLight extends Enumeration {
    type TrafficLight = Value
    val red, yellow, green = Value
}
```

I've built **encoder & decoder** for the *traffic light*:

```
implicit val trafficLightDecoder: Decoder[TrafficLight.Value] = Decoder.enumDecoder(TrafficLight)
implicit val trafficLightEncoder: Encoder[TrafficLight.Value] = Encoder.enumEncoder(TrafficLight)
```

I've also built an **encoder** for the *Map[String,String]* type:

```
implicit val encodeMap: Encoder[Map[String, String]] = new 
Encoder[Map[String, String]] {
override def apply(values: Map[String, String]): Json = {
  values.toList
    .map(pair => Json.obj(
      (pair._1, pair._2.asJson)
    )).asJson
    }
}
```

And finally, **encoder and decoder** for the **Road** case class:

```
implicit val roadDecoder: Decoder[Road] = deriveDecoder
implicit val roadEncoder: Encoder[Road] = deriveEncoder
```

Now, I'm trying to parse the json to `List[Road]`.

```
roadJson.as[List[Road]].toOption.getOrElse(List[Road]())
```

But I can't decode it - I always get an empty list, due the "else" in the `getOrElse` method, without any errors.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `.toOption.getOrElse` you discard the error that may be returned when parsing your json.

If you want to see the error, you need to look at the value returned by `roadJson.as[List[Road]]`

My favorite choice here is to use pattern matching to look at the result:

```
roadJson.as[List[Road]] match {
  case Left(error) => 
    println(error) // print to debug the error
    ... // do something in case of error
  case Right(roads) => ... // do something else
}
```

Also the json you pasted is not valid, it uses `=` instead of `:`